# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, row

I want to read the values of row in a `datatable` for that I Implemented something like this.

```
$('#entry-grid').on('click', '.check', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");            
        var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row.data();
        alert(data);
    })
```

and below is my table

```
<table id="entry-grid" datatable="" dtinstance="dtInstanceCallback" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover"></table>
```

But while debugging I am getting error as

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined

don't know why its giving the error

**UPDATE**

Here is my updated anuglar code which I am trying to work it out but its not.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['datatables']);
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder',
    function ($scope, $http, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null, '').renderWith(function(data, type, full) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-object-id="'+full.objectid+'">'
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("OBJECTID", "ID"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_CODE", "Service Code"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND1", "Condition 1"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND2", "Condition 2"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("COND3", "Condition 3"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("SERVICE_TYPE", "Service type"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("REMARK", "Remark"),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("DESCRIPTION", "Description")
        ]
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
            url: "/home/getdata",
            type: "POST"
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withDisplayLength(10);

        $scope.dtInstance = {};
        $scope.dtIntanceCallback = function (instance) {
            $scope.dtInstance = instance;            
        }
        $scope.dtRebind = function () {
            $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.draw()
        }

        $('#entry-grid').on('click', '.check', function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var data = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable.row().data(); // here is the error of row undefined            
        })        
    }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the right directive to use should be `dt-instance` instead of `dtinstance` since you are accessing it as `$scope.dtInstance` which is camel-cased so the equivalent directive would be kebab-cased.

```
<table id="entry-grid" datatable="" dt-instance="dtInstanceCallback" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover"></table>
```

Comment: ohh, i guess then its my mistake..let me try and check

Comment: i have updated my question, have a look and if possible help me out

Comment: can I ask u one question here ?

Comment: Yes, what is it?

Comment: I am always getting the first row checked, even after If I check the second or third row.. why ?? can it be set dynamically

Comment: I'm not sure why. I haven't touched Angular for quite awhile now. Can you make a fiddle or codesandbox of the issue and I'll see what I can do.